# const and let declarations in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-web-ide, ui5-tooling, blanket.js

I would like to know if it's secure to use `let` and `const` keywords while working with UI5. I don't know if returning a `let`, `const`, or even creating for instance a `sap.m.Table` with `let` would have adverse effects.

Maybe someone has some previous experience with this?

Comment: If someone plans to use ES6+ features generally in the UI5 project, see the "Note" section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841062/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you are afraid of browser incompatibilities? `let` and `const` are constructs for declaring variables; they do not affect object lifetimes. `let` declares a block scope variable whilst `const` declares a read-only variable. The objects contained in these variables have a completely different life cycle.

This is not really a UI5 issue, but a general JavaScript issue. Regardless of the libraries that you are using, the compatibility of your app will be determined by two factors:

- The compatibility matrix of each of the library that you are using.
- The compatibility of the code that you are writing.

As you can't really control the compatibility [matrix of UI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933.html) (which should cover the compatibility matrix for ES6), it all boils down to two major questions that you have to ask yourself:

- What browsers do I support?
- Can I use something to transpile my code to support older browsers?

For the first question, if you only care for browsers which can support natively ES6 ([not IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=es6)), then you can definitely use it. Otherwise, the second question might make more sense. If you have a decent C.I. pipeline in place for your app, then you could use something like [babel](http://babeljs.io) to transform your shiny ES6 code into the verbose spaghetti that IE loves so much.

---

#### Later edit:

As per the comments, I would point out that ES6 is not a supported in an all-or-nothing fashion. Feature sub-sets (like support for const and let) may be available for some browsers (IE) even if ES6 in its entirety is not. Concretely, based on https://caniuse.com/#feat=let and https://caniuse.com/#feat=const, it seems that `let` and `const` are available in IE11 (but not in older versions). Other features like [ES6 class definitions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

### UI5 1.116+

UI5 now officially allows use of ES6 syntax if the target UI5 version is 1.116 or higher. The "restriction" from the topic [Browser and Platform Support](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933) has been updated accordingly:

> ##### ⚠ Restriction
>
> With OpenUI5 1.116, the framework leverages features of modern ECMAScript up to and including ECMAScript 2022 Language Specification. **Certain restrictions do apply, however.** For more information, see **[ECMAScript Support](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/0cb44d7a147640a0890cefa5fd7c7f8e).**

The below "Note" section still applies.

### UI5 1.115 or lower (previous answer)

The [documentation still warns](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933) about the possible incompatibility with UI5:

> ##### ⚠ Restriction
>
> We currently do **not** guarantee that newer ECMAScript standards, such as ES6/ES2015, work with OpenUI5.

On the other hand, I've been using ES6+ features (including `const` and `let`) with UI5 without any issues so far.

## Note

- In order to support building the application with ES6+ syntax in the application code with ...

  - **UI5 Tooling:** upgrade the npm dependency `@ui5/cli` at least to the 3.0 version. See ["ECMAScript Support" in UI5 Tooling](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/blob/main/docs/pages/ESSupport.md) for more information.
  - **SAP Web IDE:** if your project still depends on the legacy `@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build`, ensure its version is at least 1.3.65 or newer e.g. 1.4.0.

- Reporting the code coverage with the legacy `blanket.js` library version lower than 1.2.0 fails if ES6+ syntax is used for the target project. Even if no ES6+ syntax is used, the UI5 bootstrap config `sap-ui-async` has to be disabled in order to allow the code coverage report with `blanket.js`. Subscribe to [OpenUI5 issue #3540](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3540) to get notified about the latest development regarding the code coverage report feature in UI5 projects.

Answer (score 1):

SAP WebIDE can deploy ES6 let/const syntax as long as you use a newer version of the build module.

Just use: "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.65"